# SQL Select Help

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I'm trying to count how many created vs published posts there are per user in my database.

```
POST ID | USER ID | STATUS
```

...and an example would be

> User ID 1 has 5 posts (5 distinct post IDs) with 3 STATUS = CREATED and 2 STATUS = PUBLISHED. I want the output to show the following columns

```
USER  CREATED  PUBLISHED 
----------------------------
 1    3        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.user,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.status = 'CREATED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS created,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.status = 'PUBLISHED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS published
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.user
```

Comment: does this work for MYSQL? (nevermind, got it to work...am goign to accept your answer in 2 minutes) thanks for the help ponies